# Count values by range include zero count values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've made a query that counts the values based on their range. I am expecting the query to include the range even if the count is 0.

```
select 
    case 
        when rm.VALUE < 0 then '-LOW'
        when rm.VALUE > 0 and rm.VALUE <= 5 then    '00-05'
        when rm.VALUE > 5 and rm.VALUE <= 10 then   '05-10'
        when rm.VALUE > 10 and rm.VALUE <= 10.5 then    '10-10.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 10.5 and rm.VALUE <= 11 then    '10.5-11'
        when rm.VALUE > 11 and rm.VALUE <= 11.5 then    '11-11.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 11.5 and rm.VALUE <= 12 then    '11.5-12'
        when rm.VALUE > 12 and rm.VALUE <= 12.5 then    '12-12.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 12.5 and rm.VALUE <= 13 then    '12.5-13'
        when rm.VALUE > 13 and rm.VALUE <= 13.5 then    '13-13.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 13.5 and rm.VALUE <= 14 then    '13.5-14'
        when rm.VALUE > 14 and rm.VALUE <= 14.5 then    '14-14.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 14.5 and rm.VALUE <= 15 then    '14.5-15'
        when rm.VALUE > 15 and rm.VALUE <= 15.5 then    '15-15.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 15.5 and rm.VALUE <= 16 then    '15.5-16'
        when rm.VALUE > 16 and rm.VALUE <= 16.5 then    '16-16.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 16.5 and rm.VALUE <= 17 then    '16.5-17'
        when rm.VALUE > 17 and rm.VALUE <= 17.5 then    '17-17.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 17.5 and rm.VALUE <= 18 then    '17.5-18'
        when rm.VALUE > 18 and rm.VALUE <= 18.5 then    '18-18.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 18.5 and rm.VALUE <= 19 then    '18.5-19'
        when rm.VALUE > 19 and rm.VALUE <= 19.5 then    '19-19.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 19.5 and rm.VALUE <= 20 then    '19.5-20'
        when rm.VALUE > 20 and rm.VALUE <= 20.5 then    '20-20.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 20.5 and rm.VALUE <= 21 then    '20.5.21'
        when rm.VALUE > 21 and rm.VALUE <= 21.5 then    '21-21.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 21.5 and rm.VALUE <= 22 then    '21.5-22'
        when rm.VALUE > 22 and rm.VALUE <= 22.5 then    '22-22.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 22.5 and rm.VALUE <= 23 then    '22.5-23'
        when rm.VALUE > 23 and rm.VALUE <= 23.5 then    '23-23.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 23.5 and rm.VALUE <= 24 then    '23.5-24'
        when rm.VALUE > 24 and rm.VALUE <= 24.5 then    '24-24.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 24.5 and rm.VALUE <= 25 then    '24.5-25'
        when rm.VALUE > 25 and rm.VALUE <= 25.5 then    '25-25.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 25.5 and rm.VALUE <= 26 then    '25.5.26'
        when rm.VALUE > 26 and rm.VALUE <= 26.5 then    '26-26.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 26.5 and rm.VALUE <= 27 then    '26.5-27'
        when rm.VALUE > 27 and rm.VALUE <= 27.5 then    '27-27.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 27.5 and rm.VALUE <= 28 then    '27.5-28'
        when rm.VALUE > 28 and rm.VALUE <= 28.5 then    '28-28.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 28.5 and rm.VALUE <= 29 then    '28.5-29'
        when rm.VALUE > 29 and rm.VALUE <= 29.5 then    '29-29.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 29.5 and rm.VALUE <= 30 then    '29.5-30'
        when rm.VALUE > 30 and rm.VALUE <= 30.5 then    '30-30.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 30.5 and rm.VALUE <= 31 then    '30.5-31'
        when rm.VALUE > 31 and rm.VALUE <= 31.5 then    '31-31.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 31.5 and rm.VALUE <= 32 then    '31.5-32'
        when rm.VALUE > 32 and rm.VALUE <= 32.5 then    '32-32.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 32.5 and rm.VALUE <= 33 then    '32.5-33'
        when rm.VALUE > 33 and rm.VALUE <= 33.5 then    '33-33.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 33.5 and rm.VALUE <= 34 then    '33.5-34'
        when rm.VALUE > 34 and rm.VALUE <= 34.5 then    '34-34.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 34.5 and rm.VALUE <= 35 then    '34.5-35'
        when rm.VALUE > 35 and rm.VALUE <= 35.5 then    '35-35.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 35.5 and rm.VALUE <= 36 then    '35.5-36'
        when rm.VALUE > 36 and rm.VALUE <= 36.5 then    '36-36.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 36.5 and rm.VALUE <= 37 then    '36.5-37'
        when rm.VALUE > 37 and rm.VALUE <= 37.5 then    '37-37.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 37.5 and rm.VALUE <= 38 then    '37.5-38'
        when rm.VALUE > 38 and rm.VALUE <= 38.5 then    '38-38.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 38.5 and rm.VALUE <= 39 then    '38.5-39'
        when rm.VALUE > 39 and rm.VALUE <= 39.5 then    '39-39.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 39.5 and rm.VALUE <= 40 then    '39.5-40'
           else 'HIGH'
        end as [RANGE], 
        isnull(count(1),0) as [Count]
from Tbl_roomMonitoring rm
--where Timestamp between '2023-05-15 00:00:00' and '2023-05-15 23:59:59'
group by 
    case 
        when rm.VALUE < 0 then '-LOW'
        when rm.VALUE > 0 and rm.VALUE <= 5 then        '00-05'
        when rm.VALUE > 5 and rm.VALUE <= 10 then       '05-10'
        when rm.VALUE > 10 and rm.VALUE <= 10.5 then    '10-10.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 10.5 and rm.VALUE <= 11 then    '10.5-11'
        when rm.VALUE > 11 and rm.VALUE <= 11.5 then    '11-11.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 11.5 and rm.VALUE <= 12 then    '11.5-12'
        when rm.VALUE > 12 and rm.VALUE <= 12.5 then    '12-12.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 12.5 and rm.VALUE <= 13 then    '12.5-13'
        when rm.VALUE > 13 and rm.VALUE <= 13.5 then    '13-13.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 13.5 and rm.VALUE <= 14 then    '13.5-14'
        when rm.VALUE > 14 and rm.VALUE <= 14.5 then    '14-14.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 14.5 and rm.VALUE <= 15 then    '14.5-15'
        when rm.VALUE > 15 and rm.VALUE <= 15.5 then    '15-15.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 15.5 and rm.VALUE <= 16 then    '15.5-16'
        when rm.VALUE > 16 and rm.VALUE <= 16.5 then    '16-16.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 16.5 and rm.VALUE <= 17 then    '16.5-17'
        when rm.VALUE > 17 and rm.VALUE <= 17.5 then    '17-17.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 17.5 and rm.VALUE <= 18 then    '17.5-18'
        when rm.VALUE > 18 and rm.VALUE <= 18.5 then    '18-18.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 18.5 and rm.VALUE <= 19 then    '18.5-19'
        when rm.VALUE > 19 and rm.VALUE <= 19.5 then    '19-19.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 19.5 and rm.VALUE <= 20 then    '19.5-20'
        when rm.VALUE > 20 and rm.VALUE <= 20.5 then    '20-20.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 20.5 and rm.VALUE <= 21 then    '20.5.21'
        when rm.VALUE > 21 and rm.VALUE <= 21.5 then    '21-21.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 21.5 and rm.VALUE <= 22 then    '21.5-22'
        when rm.VALUE > 22 and rm.VALUE <= 22.5 then    '22-22.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 22.5 and rm.VALUE <= 23 then    '22.5-23'
        when rm.VALUE > 23 and rm.VALUE <= 23.5 then    '23-23.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 23.5 and rm.VALUE <= 24 then    '23.5-24'
        when rm.VALUE > 24 and rm.VALUE <= 24.5 then    '24-24.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 24.5 and rm.VALUE <= 25 then    '24.5-25'
        when rm.VALUE > 25 and rm.VALUE <= 25.5 then    '25-25.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 25.5 and rm.VALUE <= 26 then    '25.5.26'
        when rm.VALUE > 26 and rm.VALUE <= 26.5 then    '26-26.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 26.5 and rm.VALUE <= 27 then    '26.5-27'
        when rm.VALUE > 27 and rm.VALUE <= 27.5 then    '27-27.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 27.5 and rm.VALUE <= 28 then    '27.5-28'
        when rm.VALUE > 28 and rm.VALUE <= 28.5 then    '28-28.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 28.5 and rm.VALUE <= 29 then    '28.5-29'
        when rm.VALUE > 29 and rm.VALUE <= 29.5 then    '29-29.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 29.5 and rm.VALUE <= 30 then    '29.5-30'
        when rm.VALUE > 30 and rm.VALUE <= 30.5 then    '30-30.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 30.5 and rm.VALUE <= 31 then    '30.5-31'
        when rm.VALUE > 31 and rm.VALUE <= 31.5 then    '31-31.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 31.5 and rm.VALUE <= 32 then    '31.5-32'
        when rm.VALUE > 32 and rm.VALUE <= 32.5 then    '32-32.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 32.5 and rm.VALUE <= 33 then    '32.5-33'
        when rm.VALUE > 33 and rm.VALUE <= 33.5 then    '33-33.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 33.5 and rm.VALUE <= 34 then    '33.5-34'
        when rm.VALUE > 34 and rm.VALUE <= 34.5 then    '34-34.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 34.5 and rm.VALUE <= 35 then    '34.5-35'
        when rm.VALUE > 35 and rm.VALUE <= 35.5 then    '35-35.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 35.5 and rm.VALUE <= 36 then    '35.5-36'
        when rm.VALUE > 36 and rm.VALUE <= 36.5 then    '36-36.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 36.5 and rm.VALUE <= 37 then    '36.5-37'
        when rm.VALUE > 37 and rm.VALUE <= 37.5 then    '37-37.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 37.5 and rm.VALUE <= 38 then    '37.5-38'
        when rm.VALUE > 38 and rm.VALUE <= 38.5 then    '38-38.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 38.5 and rm.VALUE <= 39 then    '38.5-39'
        when rm.VALUE > 39 and rm.VALUE <= 39.5 then    '39-39.5'
        when rm.VALUE > 39.5 and rm.VALUE <= 40 then    '39.5-40'
           else 'HIGH'
          end
          
    order by 
    [RANGE] asc
```

This is the result of the query.

```
RANGE   Count
16-16.5 352
16.5-17 1860
17-17.5 2859
17.5-18 5830
18-18.5 8160
18.5-19 10630
19-19.5 18112
19.5-20 19205
20-20.5 20593
20.5.21 20363
21-21.5 15933
21.5-22 19221
22-22.5 14155
22.5-23 12566
23-23.5 7830
23.5-24 6466
24-24.5 3138
24.5-25 1655
25-25.5 757
25.5.26 1158
26-26.5 803
26.5-27 1297
27-27.5 2237
27.5-28 2179
28-28.5 1518
28.5-29 1177
29-29.5 785
29.5-30 404
30-30.5 178
30.5-31 35
```

This is the result that I am expecting.

```
RANGE   Count
-LOW    0
00-05   0
05-10   0
10.5-11 0
11-11.5 0
11.5-12 0
12-12.5 0
12.5-13 0
13-13.5 0
13.5-14 0
14-14.5 0
14.5-15 0
15-15.5 0
15.5-16 0
16-16.5 352
16.5-17 1860
17-17.5 2859
17.5-18 5830
18-18.5 8160
18.5-19 10630
19-19.5 18112
19.5-20 19205
20-20.5 20593
20.5.21 20363
21-21.5 15933
21.5-22 19221
22-22.5 14155
22.5-23 12566
23-23.5 7830
23.5-24 6466
24-24.5 3138
24.5-25 1655
25-25.5 757
25.5.26 1158
26-26.5 803
26.5-27 1297
27-27.5 2237
27.5-28 2179
28-28.5 1518
28.5-29 1177
29-29.5 785
29.5-30 404
30-30.5 178
30.5-31 35
So on and so forth.
HIGH    N
```

Comment: In SQL Server queries can only return data that is available at the source tables (i.e. in the `FROM` part of the query). If you want more data to be returned you need to add it.

Comment: Yeah, for this sort of problem you need to join on each range your expect in order to provide a 0 count.

Comment: `JOIN`ing to a numbers table will probably be a much more easily read query as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is simply provide the ranges as rows, then left join your data to those ranges e.g. `left join data on data.col > range_from and data.col <= range_to` By using this approach every range will be in the final result even if there is no matching data to count

I simply converted your case expression into values to produce this:

```
select
   range_from,range_to,range_name, count(left_joined_table.*) -- count only from the left joined data
from (
  values
          (-9999999999,0,'-LOW'), (0,5,'00-05'), (5,10,'05-10')
        , (10,10.5,'10-10.5'), (10.5,11,'10.5-11'), (11,11.5,'11-11.5'), (11.5,12,'11.5-12'), (12,12.5,'12-12.5')
        , (12.5,13,'12.5-13'), (13,13.5,'13-13.5'), (13.5,14,'13.5-14'), (14,14.5,'14-14.5'), (14.5,15,'14.5-15')
        , (15,15.5,'15-15.5'), (15.5,16,'15.5-16'), (16,16.5,'16-16.5'), (16.5,17,'16.5-17'), (17,17.5,'17-17.5')
        , (17.5,18,'17.5-18'), (18,18.5,'18-18.5'), (18.5,19,'18.5-19'), (19,19.5,'19-19.5'), (19.5,20,'19.5-20')
        , (20,20.5,'20-20.5'), (20.5,21,'20.5.21'), (21,21.5,'21-21.5'), (21.5,22,'21.5-22'), (22,22.5,'22-22.5')
        , (22.5,23,'22.5-23'), (23,23.5,'23-23.5'), (23.5,24,'23.5-24'), (24,24.5,'24-24.5'), (24.5,25,'24.5-25')
        , (25,25.5,'25-25.5'), (25.5,26,'25.5.26'), (26,26.5,'26-26.5'), (26.5,27,'26.5-27'), (27,27.5,'27-27.5')
        , (27.5,28,'27.5-28'), (28,28.5,'28-28.5'), (28.5,29,'28.5-29'), (29,29.5,'29-29.5'), (29.5,30,'29.5-30')
        , (30,30.5,'30-30.5'), (30.5,31,'30.5-31'), (31,31.5,'31-31.5'), (31.5,32,'31.5-32'), (32,32.5,'32-32.5')
        , (32.5,33,'32.5-33'), (33,33.5,'33-33.5'), (33.5,34,'33.5-34'), (34,34.5,'34-34.5'), (34.5,35,'34.5-35')
        , (35,35.5,'35-35.5'), (35.5,36,'35.5-36'), (36,36.5,'36-36.5'), (36.5,37,'36.5-37'), (37,37.5,'37-37.5')
        , (37.5,38,'37.5-38'), (38,38.5,'38-38.5'), (38.5,39,'38.5-39'), (39,39.5,'39-39.5'), (39.5,40,'39.5-40')
        , (40,9999999999,'HIGH')
 ) range (range_from,range_to,range_name)
left join left_joined_table on left_joined_table.col > range_from
                           and left_joined_table.col <= range_to
group by
   range_from,range_to,range_name
```

It might be possible to generate a set of ranges using a recursive CTE, but here I think using values is more than sufficient.

As a final note, it is more common in my experience for ranges to work `somecol >= range_from and somecol < range_to` but there is no mandate on this I guess.

Comment: Thank you! This query works, but it is returning 1 even if the count is 0.

Comment: It is important to **NOT** use `count(*)` you **MUST** put a column reference to the left joined data inside the count function e.g.  `count(left_joined_table.*)` replacing "left_joined_table" as appropriate to what you have in fact joined...

Comment: Yep, this works. The query is now working properly. Thank you again!